# Aparecen textos sin sentido en mi pagina

Tags: angular, angular7, meta-tags

Holaaa! traigo un problemita del cual no logro encontrar solución.

Tengo una SPA hecha con Angular 7, y de manera aleatoria me aparecen textos que no están en el código. Estos textos o caracteres no aparecen de la nada, se reemplazan por algún dato estático o dinámico.

Dejo una captura del calendario que esta implementado en dicha pagina, ahí se ve claramente como en vez de aparecer 1982, aparece "mil novecientos ochenta y dos".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo acá el head:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Autogestión</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.jpg">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Agradezco un montón la ayuda! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes asegurarte de que no tienes una extensión en tu navegador con funciones de "traducción" o similares (Estas pueden cambiar el texto de la página inadvertidamente).

Descartada esa posibilidad te recomiendo le eches un vistazo a otros plugins de calendario para Angular.

Para elegir un buen plugin considera lo siguiente:

- Soporte (Entre más personas lo usen, mejor será su soporte)
- Tamaño (Entre más ligero sea, más rápida será tu SPA)
- Actividad (¿Hace cuánto fue la última contribución hecha al proyecto?)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El caso del calendario es un ejemplo entre otros tantos que surgen de manera aleatoria. Al limpiar cache se soluciona. El problema esta en que esta pagina la usan mas de 6000 personas, por lo que el borrado de cache deja de ser una opción viable, ya que dependería de cada usuario.

Comment: Sería bueno conocer las dependencias de tu proyecto, saber un poco sobre su arquitectura para comenzar a debuggear. En sistemas grandes es fácil perder de vista algún feature que impacta a todo lo demás.